# mvn clean package on javaee-samples : Could not find artifact org.javaee7:test-utils:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in codehaus-snapshots

Tags: java, maven

That is many examples on javaEE maven projects on github, but when I try to clean this one : https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples, I got errors in command line, please what is wrong in the pom.xml :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cdi-decorators: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.javaee7:cdi-decorators:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.javaee7:test-utils:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/) -> [Help 1]
```

That's a part of the pom.xml   :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codehaus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>codehaus-snapshots</id>
        <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

What I am missing ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to run only parts of the proect cause the build is a multi module build and you are running only parts of it. You have to go to the root of the project and there you can call `mvn package` which should work. The test-utils which are not found are part of the whole project.

Comment: firstly, Thanks for answer, but when I try "mvn package", I got this error :

***********************************************************************************
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project cdi-decorators: There are test failures.

************************************************************************************
Can I remove all tests to resolve it, if yes, how can I do it please ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From root of samples i.e javaee7-samples directory: 
`mvn -DskipTests=true clean install`

From javaee7-samples/cdi/decorators directory: 
`mvn test`

Answer (score 1):

you can use also 
mvn clean install -DskipTests